# Beamer `\bibliographystyle{alpha}` force no plus symbol

Tags: beamer, bibtex

I am referencing in beamer with `\bibliography{myFile.bib}` and `\bibliographystyle{alpha}`

The following label is produced for three authors or less:

- [ABC14]

The following label is produced for four authors or more:

- [ABC<sup>+</sup>14]

Is there a way to force no plus symbol?

Comment: Any luck? I'd love to have a solution to this as well.

Comment: No. For now I left it with the plus.

Answer (score 1):

I switched to `biblatex`, and used the following options:

```
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,minnames=6,maxnames=6]{biblatex}
```